# Declare global property type only when a specific module is imported

Tags: typescript

I have a module that adds a property to the global object. This module is part of a test environment setup so it's only executed for certain tests/files. I want to declare the global property it sets but only for those files.

I tried declaring it in an TS file that exports an empty then importing that file, but it still impacts all the files in the project.

```js
// env/index.ts

declare global {
   var foo: Foo
}

export {}
```

```js
// __tests__/bar.test.ts
import 'env';

foo.fooMethod() // foo is type Foo ✅
```

```js
// randomOtherFile.ts
// foo is also type Foo ❌
```

Is there a way to extend the global object only when importing a specific module?

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to use an interface instead of a global scope, since you only need this in specific files.

Example of interface:

```js
// env/fooModule.ts

export interface Foo {
    fooMethod(): void;
}

export const foo: Foo = {
    fooMethod() {
        console.log('I am of type Foo')
    }
};
```

Then you can import and use the module whereever needed as follows -

```js
// __tests__/bar.test.ts
import { foo } from '../env/fooModule';

foo.fooMethod(); // foo is type Foo ✅
```

Where the import is missing in other random files, it will not be of type `Foo`.

The global scope will always apply the change uniformly across all files. You cannot selectively apply a global scope else the semantics would change :)

Comment: The environment setup creates an instance and adds it to the `global` object because the tests run in multiple threads with different instances for each thread with different options. So importing doesn't work because it wouldn't be the same instance.

Comment: In that case you can export an instance of a class and use it as a shared object for the specific files.